# Passing DbContext instance into method within a using statement

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I have several business objects that wrap my data models I created using Entity Framework 6. These business objects all have CRUD methods to interact with the data models.

For simplicity let's only look at the `Get()` function. I instantiate the context, and then I'll get the reference. The `Get()` function also has a parameter to determine if we should get values related to the client, `ClientValues`. `ClientValues` is also a business object that contains aforementioned CRUD operations.

So my question is, rather than creating a new instance of the context in `ClientValues.Get()`, should I be passing the current context reference and use that? Will this even be more efficient or is .NET smart enough to handle this? I've already tried this and it appears that context gets disposed when I pass it into another method, but I assume there is a proper way of doing this?

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ClientValue> ClientValues { get; set; }
    ...

    public void Get(int id, bool getValues)
    {
        using (var context = new MyDbEntities()) // MyDbEntities inherits DbContext obviously
        {
            var efClientModel = context.Clients.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            // populate business object
            if (getValues)
            {
                foreach (var value in efClientModel.ClientValues)
                {
                    var newValue = new ClientValue();
                    newValue.Get(value.Id, context); // this is where I pass the context in
                    this.ClientValues.Add(newValue);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

What `ClientValues.Get()` looks like:

```
 public void Get(int valueId, MyDbEntities passedContext = null)
 {
     using (var context = passedContext == null ? new MyDbEntities() : passedContext)
     {
         ...
     }
 }
```

Comment: Whatever _creates_ the context should dispose of it - do NOT wrap the passed in context in _another_ `using` block.

Comment: Also a larger design decision would be "not tightly coupling your entities to the data source.  That's typically encapsulated in a repository or other pattern.

Comment: You might find this worth reading: http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/

Comment: Is `Client` an entity class? (I.e. a mapped class)

Comment: @GertArnold Yes it is (determined this after googling); my knowledge in proper terminology isn't very broad :D

Comment: So why do you have these `Get` methods? Why don't you get a `Client` and its adhering `ClientValues` by one LINQ query?

Comment: @DStanley Okay that makes sense. So let's say I do it this way, but do not pass in a context, how would I "switch" the using statement off or on based on if the default param is null or not without duplicating my code? Should I create a private `Get` method that is called in the public `Get` ?

Comment: @GertArnold The idea was to create a intermediary class so that I'm not dealing directly with the data models, as I have several business rules that I will be applying before I can insert, update etc...

Comment: @JonathanCarroll Either that or use a `try/finally` block and dispose of the context _if you created it_.

Comment: I can't tell if this helps you to apply business rules better, but the usual way to get clients would be something like `context.Clients.Include(c => c.ClientValues).Where(...)`. It's usually a bad idea to have entity classes take care of their own data access. For one, you'll fire separate queries for each entity to be materialized, while it can all be done in one query.

Comment: @GertArnold I can see where my implementation may decrease efficiency. I'm not too familiar with EF just yet so I was having a lot of trouble with the way it handles foreign key collections and lazy loading etc so that played a large role in my decision of using entity classes. Do you happen to know of any good articles or books that would explain this more in depth or show better implementations of what I am trying to do? My google-fu is failing me.

Comment: Maybe here: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend not having your entities responsible for any database operations. But if you do choose to continue down this path, I would strongly suggest having all your `Get()` operations accept the `DbContext` as a paramter, with the context owned by whatever needs to do the `Get`ing (with the "owner" responsible for the `using`).